# My keyboard types " instantly so i can't create e with " on top

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

Windows 10.

Keyboard types ', " and ` instantly, and I can't make special letters because of this.

Comment: Are you using laptop or desktop computer? Have you tried connecting external keyboard to the laptop or switching keyboards for the desktop and see if the issue gets solved? Update your question with these details.

Answer (score 2):

That's the normal way most keyboard layouts work. To activate the [dead-key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_key) behavior for <kbd>'</kbd> <kbd>"</kbd> <kbd>`</kbd> keys, you'll need to select the **US (International)** layout in keyboard settings.